# How to merge Sorting Layers in Unity?

Tags: unity

I have two unity3d projects, both are using sprite renderers and sorting layers.
Project 1 has Following Sorting Layers:

1. Default
2. Tile Map
3. Items
4. Animals
5. UI
6. Particles

Project 2 has Following Sorting Layers:

1. Default
2. Background
3. Slots
4. Chips
5. Foreground
6. Map
7. UI

Project 1 is my main project. I need to merge these both projects. I created new layers in project 1 and then imported project 2 but sorting layers of project 2 are broken .Setting each layer again in project 2 is very difficult task and rework. How can i merge these two project without breaking any sorting layer or tags ?